# A multiple of $(1111+912)^{(1111+912)^{(1111+912)}}$ without using the digits "$0$", "$13$" and "$666$"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Anna claims that it is possible to write a number that is a multiple of $2023^{2023^{2023}}$ without using the digit "$0$" and the sequences of digits "$13$" and "$666$", but superstitious Timur says that it's impossible. Who is right? Explain your answer using mathematics, not superstition.

This is an Olympiad question for students in grades 10–12 organized by a Russian university.

How this could be solved?

Comment: Can I write $(1111+912)^{(1111+912)^{1111+912}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that the arbitrary restrictions could be further strengthened: in fact, we claim that we can write a multiple of $2023^k$ for any $k$ *using only $9$s*, which is clearly sufficient.

To do this, we need to find a value of $n$ such that
$$
10^n \equiv 1 \pmod{2023^k}
$$
(as then, $2023^k \mid 10^n - 1$, and $10^n - 1$ is a sequence of $n$ consecutive $9$s). However, note that $\gcd(10, 2023) = 1$, so by Euler's totient theorem $n = \phi(2023^k)$ suffices.